# Autocomplete in vscode not showing some code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

some code does not appear. I have to type it manually. For example, if I want to add an upper, it does not appear

```
print(f'Hello {first.upper().capitalize()})
```

It does not complete here, but in other things it completes

Nothing works for me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiUGk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined a variable named **first**, but it has no content. It can be of any type, so vscode won't provide any prompt.

I guess that you want to define the **string** and first is it's content.

[image]

You can define `x="first"`, here the type of **x** is string, then x has the `upper()` method.